# Add, Update and delete using single transaction EF 6?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have  method which has following signature

performAmmend(Project project, List witem, List cConfig)

the relationship is
Project->WorkItem ( 1 to many)
WorkItem->CustomConfig( 1 to many )

List parameter could have some new entries, modified or deleted

How to perform update operation for the project using transaction?
i am using code first approch in Entity framework 6.x.

Answer (score 0):

EF will give you a [transaction by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx). So simply setup your object graph and apply SaveChanges(). OK, deep object graphs aren't simple, but you could use a tool like [graphdiff](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/)